# Make div overflow scroll on the x axis

Tags: php, html, css, scroll

I scan trough a folder for images by using php,
i put them in a div with the ID of images.
I want that div to scroll on the x-axis and hide everything that overflows on the y-axis.

So here's my code.

HTML and PHP:

```
<div id="images">
<?php
//Displaying images
$imgID = 0;
foreach($images as $image) {
    echo "<img id='img".$imgID."' onClick='displayImg(".$imgID.");' src='".$image."' height='".$imgHeight."' width='".$imgWidth."' />";
    $imgID++;
}
echo "<script>var maxImages = ".$imgID.";</script>";
?>
```

CSS:

```
#images {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    height:<?php echo $imgHeight; ?>px;
    border:solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    align-content:flex-start;
}
#images img {
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
float:left;
}
```

I've experimented a bit, But nothing i've tried seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing i've tried seems to work"? Why do you say its not working, what happens?

Comment: @LcSalazar What happens is that the images float left, but instead of continuing to the right and makes the x-axis scrollable, It shows down on the y-axis if you remove the overflow-y property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is slightly out of context but how about something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/u9Xx6/

This goes on the assumption that you have the image widths available in php (`$imgWidth`) which can allow you to create a large inner container.

Failing that you may need to give us a JSFiddle to demonstrate your issue in greater detail...